# Searching an array for a substring

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
[CALLGUID] => 200667992044
[CALLERID] => +9167555555
[CALLDATEEST] => 2014-08-13
[CALLTIMEEST] => 01:21:30
[COUNTRY] => 
[LOCALCALLTIME] => 16:00:00
[LOCALDATE] => 1969-12-31
[REGIONID] => 0
[DOW] => 0
)
```

I wan't to know if CALLERID has a "+" in it so I can do some calculations, I have tried a few different methods such as substr, and array_search but I am having no luck.  This is where I'm at right now ..

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regionCheck)) {  
 if(array_search('+',$r['CALLERID'])){
    echo "Inside + removing the +, it is an international call." ."\n";
  }
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: I'm getting down voted because I misunderstood something?  Keep it up Stack-overflow..

Comment: Not **you** got downvoted, *your question* did. Don't take it too personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to start with, you are using `array_search()` incorrectly. You need to pass it an array, `$r`, not a string, `$r['CALLERID']`. I also couldn't get it to find just a `+`, so I switched your `if` statement around and used a `strstr()` on `$r['CALLERID']` as you already know exactly which key you are looking at, you don't need to dance around. Just target it directly.

```
if(strstr($r['CALLERID'],"+")){
    echo "Inside + removing the +, it is an international call." ."\n";
}
```

This will yield the results you expected from your code.